# Does Spark improve performance with huge dataframe and machine learning algorithm that is not available in MLlib?

Tags: python, performance, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I’m training a machine learning model in python 3, but it’s taking long. I have a very large dataframe and the algorithm I’m using isn’t available in Spark MLlib. Is there any performance benefit in terms of training time by uploading my dataframe into Spark and using a non-MLlib algorithm?

In terms of manipulating the dataframe, I understand manipulating it will be faster, but if the algorithm isn’t distributed, I am not sure if it would speed up training. I’m new to Spark and am not sure if I’m understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Spark could help with training a model, even if the model isn't part of the Spark standard library.  It all depends on if you leverage the power of cluster computing when training the model.  Suppose you have a 20 node i3.xlarge cluster (30.5 GB of RAM per node) and have all nodes crunching data in parallel to train your model.  That's essentially a 610 GB supercomputer at your fingertips.

If you don't structure the code properly, you might accidentally perform all the computations on the driver node and only use one of the nodes in your cluster, leaving the other ones idle.

Spark is also powerful for running models on huge datasets.  Suppose you have a Python model that takes a bunch of inputs and returns an output.  Spark is a great way to run this model on lets say 50 billion rows of data.

Not sure why you're getting downvoted, this is an excellent question in my opinion.